# Update control backcolor at desing-time

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, user-controls

I've inherited a listbox control to write some properties like this:

```
''' <summary>
''' Indicates the BackColor to paint the unselected ListBox items when the ListBox is enabled.
''' </summary>
Public Property ItemUnselected_BackColor As Color
    Get
        Return _ItemUnselected_BackColor.Color
    End Get
    Set(value As Color)
        _ItemUnselected_BackColor = New SolidBrush(value)
    End Set
End Property
```

The problem is that when I change the color at design, I need to move the control or minimize/maximize VisualStudio IDE to update the changes on the control to see the new color.

Which is the propper way to do this?

> UPDATE:

I think that the way to do this is adding an special flag or something else...

I've tried this, but the property becomes unaccesible at the editor:

```
<EditorAttribute(GetType(Color), GetType(UITypeEditor))> _
Public Property ItemUnselected_BackColor As Color
...
```

Comment: I don't see why changing the DT editor would have any affect towards this problem.

Comment: Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå Yes you are right really I didn't knew what I was trying, sorry

Comment: example UIEditor: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687430/Selecting-Forms-Controls-at-Design-Time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is that the property is defined as a color but you are trying to work with/save a brush.  The correct method would be

```
Public Property ItemUnselected_BackColor As Color
    Get
        Return _ItemUnselected_BackColor
    End Get
    Set(value As Color)
        _ItemUnselected_BackColor = value
        Me.Invalidate
    End Set
End Property
```

And `Invalidate` would be the correct way to update the control because, well the current display is not invalid given the new color setting.  The brush, should be created in the `paint` or `OnDrawItem` procedures not in a property get/setter.  Your code is not disposing of the previous one.

Those attributes are not needed and dont do what you think they do.  They would define a special way (like a Dialog) to get the color.

That ListView of yours I started working on now has an AlternativeBack color.  If you want to optimize you can do this:

```
 Set(ByVal value As Color)
       If _AltBackColor <> value Then
           _AltBackColor = value
            Me.Invalidate()    ' only invalidate/repaint if it changed
       End If
 End Set
```

Comment: ItemUnselected_BackColor is a Color to be able to modify the color at desing (with a brush can't), but _ItemUnselected_BackColor is a brush, that's the reason why I get a color but set a brush, I think that the brush constructor does not affect and is disposed correctly because i did a performance test now to ensure it, a for range loop from 0 to 999999 to set all the time the property and no extra memory is found. if invalidating the control is the proper way then I should trust it, thankyou for all the information

Answer (score 2):

How about invalidate the control when the property changes?

```
Public Property ItemUnselected_BackColor As Color
    Get
        Return _ItemUnselected_BackColor.Color
    End Get
    Set(value As Color)
        _ItemUnselected_BackColor = New SolidBrush(value)
        Me.Invalidate(True)
    End Set
End Property
```

**EDIT**

Since it's strongly recommended only to create a brush when needed you should do it like this:

```
Public Property ItemUnselected_BackColor As Color
    Get
        Return Me._ItemUnselected_BackColor
    End Get
    Set(value As Color)
        If ((value = Color.Transparent) OrElse (value = Color.Empty)) Then
            Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException()
        End If
        If (value <> _ItemUnselected_BackColor) Then
            Me._ItemUnselected_BackColor = value
            Me.Invalidate()
        End If
    End Set
End Property

Private _ItemUnselected_BackColor As Color = Color.Black
```

And in your paint method:

```
Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
    Using b As New SolidBrush(Me._ItemUnselected_BackColor)
        'TODO: Paint
    End Using
    MyBase.OnPaint(e)
End Sub
```

Comment: thankyou but don't worked, anyways I think that invalidating the control can't be a proper way to do it.

Comment: I've updated the answer to make sure all children are validated. (If the ListBox is inside a UserControl)

Comment: guys, I instance a brush at the top class declarations, and that brush is "replaced" when I set the (color) property, then I use always the same brush object variable, really that is not better than instancing/disposing a new brush every time at the paint event?...

Comment: It's all about how you handle the brush throughout your code. If you ensure the disposal of the brush it would be okay. But i still think the field should be of same type as the reflected property.